# how to construct a union of infinite sets

Tags: set-theory

I am learning the ZF(C) set theory. In the learning progress, I am also trying to formalize some maneuvers of sets that I did without doubting before.

For example, I am trying to prove that one can construct a union of any given sets. I successfully verified the case for finite sets, by applying the axiom of pairing and the axiom of union like this:
$$\begin{align*}
&1.\quad X_1,X_2 \to \{X_1,X_2\} \tag{axiom of pairing}\\
&2.\quad X_3 \to \{X_3\} \tag{axiom of pairing}\\
&3.\quad \{X_1,X_2\},\{X_3\} \to \{X_1,X_2,X_3\} \tag{axiom of union}\\
&\vdots\\
&\vdots
\end{align*}
$$

But I don't quite know how to construct a union of infinite sets. I tried this if I can link a collection of infinite sets to a set:

Let $I$ be an infinite set, and link the known sets $X_a,X_b,\cdots$ where $a,b,\cdots \in I$. Here I have a function (say $f$) that maps each element in $I$ to a set in the given collection. So I can use the axiom of replacement to obtain the range $f(I)$, and then use the axiom of union on $f(I)$ to get the union.

But I have some questions here:

1. How can I know that for any arbitrary collection of sets, there exists a set $I$ whose "number of elements" is the same as the number of sets in the collection?
2. Assume that I know the existence of $I$, is it legal to assert the existence of the function $f$? I mean, I may not able to distinguish each set from the collection, so how do I define the rule that gives the function?
3. What if a collection of sets can't be linked to any set like this? If there is such a collection, can I make a union of the sets in it?

After all, I guess that maybe I can't make a union for all collection of sets. But I am stuck here, so I come here to ask for help.

Comment: What do you mean by collection? Is a set the same as a collection, or are they different?

Comment: @Dasherman It is not the mathematical "collection". It is the "collection" in normal English.

Comment: The modern terms would be "category" or "class" for things too big to be sets.  And yes, once you start studying the basics you start doubting everything!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, you should not expect that the union of an arbitrary collection of sets will also be a set if the collection is not a set. Let $X$ be some collection that is not a set. Consider the collection $Y$ of singleton sets of elements of $X$ (that is, "$Y=\{\{x\}: x\in X\}$"). Then the union of the sets in $Y$ is $X$, which is not a set.